# How to construct a HTML link to prefill a form field on this site

Tags: html, forms, hyperlink

i usually have no trouble constructing HTML links to prefill any given form field.
However, this one has me stumped:
https://www.planningportal.nsw.gov.au/spatialviewer/#/find-a-property/address

I want to construct a link to prefill the address here, I've used all the usual structures like the following:
https://www.planningportal.nsw.gov.au/spatialviewer/#/find-a-property/address#mat-input-0=100+Princes+St,+Ryde+NSW+2112
Also replacing the # with a ? does not work
I believe the field ID is "mat-input-0"

Is there something obvious I am missing here?
Is the site sanitising the query from the end of the link for some reason perhaps?

Comment: Afaik there is no logic which prefills form fields based on query parameters in the browser. So it has to be done on the server side (For example in php it's common to do so)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var url = "https://www.planningportal.nsw.gov.au/spatialviewer/#/find-a-property/address#mat-input-0=100+Princes+St,+Ryde+NSW+2112"
var address = url.split('mat-input-0=')[1].replace(/\+/g, ' ');
document.getElementById("address-input").value = address;
```

```html
<input id='address-input' val='' size='50' />
```

you can replace url by `var url = window.location.pathname;` to get the parameters in your url.
hope it helps :)